# Distribution of two random variables made up of the coordinates of a point

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I want to prove that random variables $$\sqrt{-\ln{X}}\cos{Y}, \sqrt{-\ln{X}}\sin{Y}$$ have the same distribution, where $(X,Y)$ is randomly selected from the square $[0;1]^2$ point. I don't know where to start. I would be very grateful for any help

Comment: You probably want to normalize differently. So that square is from 0 to 2 pi.

Comment: @ Frederik Ravn Klausen: If $X>1$ then $\sqrt{-\ln(X)}\notin \mathbb{R}$

Comment: To keep $(0,1)$ square, use $2\pi Y$ instead of $Y$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us suppose that we have $\sqrt{-\ln X} \cos 2\pi Y$ and $\sqrt{-\ln X} \sin 2\pi Y $, otherwise claim is not true.

It's easy to see that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

It's sufficient to show that $\cos 2\pi Y $ and $\sin 2\pi Y$ have the same distribuion in case $Y \sim U[-1,1]$.

We have $\cos 2\pi Y = \sin (\frac{\pi}2 - 2\pi Y) $ and $\frac{\pi}2 -  2\pi Y = \frac{\pi}2 - U[0, 2 \pi] \sim U[-\frac{3\pi}2, \frac{\pi}2] = - \pi +U[-\frac{\pi}2, \frac{\pi}2] =  - \pi  - U[-\frac{\pi}2, \frac{\pi}2]$, hence
$$cos 2\pi Y = \sin (\frac{\pi}2 - 2\pi Y) = \sin (- \pi  -U[-\frac{\pi}2, \frac{\pi}2])  = sin(U[-\frac{\pi}2, \frac{\pi}2]) $$
Similarly $$\sin (2\pi Y)  \sim sin(U[-\frac{\pi}2, \frac{\pi}2]).$$
Thus $\cos 2\pi Y = \sin 2\pi Y$ in distribution, q.e.d.

Answer (score 1):

Define the transformation $T:(0,1)^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by $$T(x,y)=\Big(\sqrt{-\ln(x)}\cos(y),\sqrt{-\ln(x)}\sin(y)\Big)=(u,v)$$ The image of $(0,1)^2$ under $T$ is the region in the first quadrant of the $(u,v)-$ plane bounded by the curves $v=0$ and $v=\tan(1)u$ which we'll represent as $\tilde{\Omega}$. Notice $$T^{-1}(u,v)=\Bigg(e^{-(u^2+v^2)},\arcsin\bigg(\frac{v}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}\bigg)\Bigg)$$ Using $T^{-1}$ we establish the joint density of $(U,V)$ with support $\tilde{\Omega}$ to be $$f_{UV}(u,v)=f_{XY}\Big(T^{-1}(u,v)\Big)\bigg|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\bigg|=2e^{-(u^2+v^2)}$$ Let's examine the marginal pdfs of $U$ and $V$: $$f_{U}(u)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{UV}(u,v)dv=2e^{-u^2}\int_0^{\tan(1)u}e^{-v^2}dv$$ $$f_{V}(v)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{UV}(u,v)du=2e^{-v^2}\int_{v/\tan(1)}^{\infty}e^{-u^2}du$$ These are not the same, so I would deduce that the the distributions of $$U=\sqrt{-\ln(X)}\cos(Y) \\ V=\sqrt{-\ln(X)}\sin(Y)$$ are different.

Comment: So much thank you! You really helped me!